# C# Model Binding to Custom Classes Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having difficulty getting MVC to bind to a model I have created. I have done this quite a few times in the past successfully. As such, I am just not sure why it is not working in this project.

For example, I have the following View:

```
    @model StoryWall.ViewModels.ViewPostViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View Post";
}

<article class="story">
    <header>
        <h1>@Model.story.Title</h1>
        <spann class="text-muted">@Model.story.Store.StoreName</span>
            <h2>Posted by @Model.story.PosterName</h2>
</header>

    if(@Model.story.StoryImage != null) {
    <div class="storyImageWrapper">
        <img src="~/img/@Model.story.StoryImage" />
    </div>

    <p>@Model.story.StoryBody</p>
    }
</article>

<div class="commentsSection">
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <h3>Add a Comment</h3>
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="CommentForm" action="/View/AddComment">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="hidden" name="newComment.StoryID" value="@Model.story.StoryID" />
        <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2">Name </label><div class="col-sm-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(@m => m.newComment.CommenterName, new { @class = "form-control", @required = true, @ng_model = "CommenterName"})  <span class="text-warning" ng-show="CommentForm.newComment.CommenterName.$dirty && CommentForm.newComment.CommenterName.$invalid"> Required </span> <span class="text-warning"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(@m => m.newComment.CommenterName) </span></div> </div>
        <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email </label><div class="col-sm-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(@m => m.newComment.CommenterEmail, new { @class = "form-control", @required = true, @ng_model = "CommenterEmail" })  <span class="text-warning" ng-show="CommentForm.newComment.CommenterEmail.$dirty && CommentForm.newComment.CommenterEmail.$invalid"> Required </span> <span class="text-warning"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(@m => m.newComment.CommenterEmail) </span></div> </div>
        <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2">Message </label><div class="col-sm-10">@Html.TextAreaFor(@m => m.newComment.CommentBody, new { @class = "form-control", @required = true, @ng_model = "CommentBody" })  <span class="text-warning" ng-show="CommentForm.newComment.CommentBody.$dirty && CommentForm.newComment.CommentBody.$invalid"> Required </span> <span class="text-warning"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(@m => m.newComment.CommentBody) </span></div> </div>
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="CommentForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <h3>Current Comments</h3>
    @foreach(var comment in @Model.story.Comments) {
        <blockquote>@comment.CommentBody</blockquote>
   <span>Poster: @comment.CommenterName on @comment.DatePosted.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")</span>

    }

</div>
```

Even though I am specifically using Html.TextBoxFor() for my input boxes, the binding is still not working as expected.

This is my Controller. "comment" in the second Action method is not binding correctly; its properties are null.

```
   public class ViewController : Controller
{

    StoryModel dbContext = new StoryModel();

    public ActionResult ViewPost(Int32 postID)
    {
        ViewPostViewModel vm = new ViewPostViewModel();
        vm.story = dbContext.Stories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StoryID == postID);
        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddComment(Comment comment)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dbContext.Comments.Add(comment);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("ViewPost", new { storyID = comment.StoryID});
        }
        else
        {
            ViewPostViewModel vm = new ViewPostViewModel();
            vm.story = dbContext.Stories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StoryID == comment.StoryID);
            vm.newComment = comment;
            return View("ViewPost", vm);
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is not the first time a similar question has been asked, but I could not find a solution that solved my problem. Additionally, as stated, this is something I have done in the past with success.

The only "new" element in this scenaria for me is Angular.js. This is my first time using the framework. Could it be interfering with the binding somehow?

If it helps, the Comment model:

```
public partial class Comment
{
    public int CommentID { get; set; }

    public int? StoryID { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(75)]
    public string CommenterName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(75)]
    public string CommenterEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CommentBody { get; set; }


    public virtual Story Story { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

and the ViewPostViewModel

```
    public class ViewPostViewModel
{

    public Story story { get; set; }
    public Comment newComment  { get; set; }
}
```

}

Thanks much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer would be to use **@Html.EditorFor()**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.newComment)
```

Then on the folder where the view is placed you create a new folder called EditorTemplates with a view that is named exactly as the object type. In this case, **Comment.cshtml**

The view could be something like this ->

```
@model StoryWall.ViewModels.Comment

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CommenterName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CommenterEmail)
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.CommentBody)
```

This approach is the one I normally use to work with lists (useful in surveys or tests) but it also works with a single item.

Another approach could be to just add everything to the viewmodel since the viewmodel doesn't need to be a one to one mapping of the business objects or the database models. :)

Edit: Forgot to add. I think using this approach the method that receives the post will have to receive the whole ViewModel instead of just the comment. ->

```
public ActionResult AddComment(ViewPostViewModel vm)
```